# SSIS Trims When copying from one Oracle VARCHAR2 to another Oracle VARCHAR2 column

Tags: oracle, ssis, etl, trim, varchar2

I'm new with SSIS. We are using it to copy data from one Oracle Database to another one. The structure of the destination is identical to the source. I expect SSIS to copy the data without any changes. But when i have a VARCHAR2 with a content like 'Hello World    ', the destination get's this: 'Hello World', SSIS trimmed all the trailing and leading spaces. Is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: Are you sure about that?! Normally SSIS dose not dot that. If we need to trim the data we have to use Derived Columns or we have to do that in Source query.

Comment: Did you test it with an Oracle database? We think it may be a problem related to the Oracle client, because strange things like this happens when you consume an oracle db with technology designed for microsoft dbs.

Comment: I have not tested it with Oracle. I had some kind of this problem with postgreSQL. the result data type in ssis for all varchar datatype in postgreSQL was NVarchar.